# How to define a function based on an operation with parameters

Tags: functions, symbolic

I would like to define a function as the output of another operation depending on a few parameters. For example

```
s[t1_,t2_]:= Integrate[t^n,{t,t1,t2}] 
s[0,1]
```

I only get back an echo s[0,1] rather than a function dependent on $a, n$. What is the correct format for the definition?

I tried the following.

```
s[n_,t1_,t2_]:= Integrate[t^n,{t,t1,t2}] 
s[2,0,1]
```

**Edit:**
I got a conditional expression after a long wait. How do I specify $n$ to be a real number for this integral?

Comment: @bills: I quit and restarted the whole thing. I got a long conditional expression after a long wait. I have edited my question. Could you please take a look at my Edit?

Comment: `Clear["Global\`*"]; 

s[n_, t1_, t2_] =
 ConditionalExpression[
  Integrate[t^n, {t, t1, t2}, Assumptions -> n > -1 && t2 > t1 >= 0],
  n > -1 && t2 > t1 >= 0]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Why do we need  the outer function ConditionalExpression[ [], n > -1 && t2 > t1 >= 0] the condition of which replicates the condition of the Assumption of the Integrate[] function?

Comment: The `ConditionalExpression` carries the knowledge of the assumptions used in the definition of `s` and ensures that the assumptions are satisfied when `s` is evaluated. For example, `s[n, -1, t2]` evaluates to `Undefined` since the arguments do not satisfy the assumptions.

Comment: @BobHanlon: But it seems s[n_, t1_, t2_] := 
 Integrate[t^n, {t, t1, t2}, Assumptions -> n > -1 && t2 > t1 > 0] does work. When I type s[n, t1, t2], it shows the right result. Is there a subtle difference?

Comment: With that definition when you evaluate `s[n, -1, t2]` instead of `Undefined` you get a warning message `Integrate::fas: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False.` and  

`Integrate[t^n, {t, -1, t2}, Assumptions -> False]`. Select whichever behavior you prefer.